# TListBox bound to TList<T> not being updated when items added to list (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, binding, firemonkey

When I create my TList of objects BEFORE setting the DataObject property on my BindScope I can see the items in my listbox

```
Damos := TList<TDamo>.Create();
Damos.Add(TDamo.Create('Damo'));
Damos.Add(TDamo.Create('Jeanette'));
theBindScope.DataObject := Damos;
```

But if I move the last line before the two Add lines, I never see the lines in the listbox.

```
Damos := TList<TDamo>.Create();
theBindScope.DataObject := Damos;
Damos.Add(TDamo.Create('Damo'));
Damos.Add(TDamo.Create('Jeanette'));
```

Shouldn't the bindings be responding to the OnNotify event from the TList ?

Comment: Please show your declarations for TDamo and theBindScope. Is theBindScope a variable of type TListBox? You need to be clear on this.

Comment: _RAD Studio does not have a notification system that informs the expression engine of any object or property change. In the sample applications, Notify is called from event handlers._ © [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/LiveBindings_in_RAD_Studio), so seems you have to notify binding in your `list.onNotify` event handler